# How to install TimescaleDB on Kali Linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I am trying to install `timescaledb` in Kali Linux. It doesn't have support for kali-rolling. The Debian package for Ubuntu is also not getting installed.

Is there any way to install it on Kali?

Comment: Did you try adding the `ubuntu` or `debian` sources?  If so what kind of output did apt give you to get "is also not getting installed"?  If this software doesn't have many dependencies, this can work (looks like it only depends on postgresql).  However, if it has a dependency on something that isn't in Kali, you'll have problems.

Comment: I got stuck resolving the dependency issues

Comment: Can you add the output of apt to your question?

Comment: It will ignore install by saying `cannot install for kali` . let me recreate it and edit the post.

Comment: @Stewart. Well I cannot even add the source to my apt sources.list

Comment: Later I tried downloading the debian package of timescaledb. It had another dependency issue . Then I tried to fix that issue by adding ubuntu `xenial`. But failed saying cannot install for kali

Comment: Again I tried to build it from source code (timescaledb) for postgres 11. But it required `postgresql-server-dev-11` which wasn't available to Kali.

Comment: I recommend read [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5362/272848) and trying a different distro.